# Return executeSQL function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, callback, closures

I'm trying to return the results of a SQL query using SQLite.
The query works fine and I can output the results inside the executeSql function. But when I try to reach the array from my main function (returnSQLArray) it is undefined. 
How do I solve this problem?

I'm calling returnSQLArray inside another function where I need the results from the query.

Code:

```
function returnSQLArray(str) 
{
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Name", 200000);
    var result = [];
    db.transaction(
        function (tx, results) {
             tx.executeSql(str, [], function(tx, rs) {
                 for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                      var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                      result[i] = {
                          id: row['id']
                      }
                 }
                 console.log(result[0].id); //Returns the id
            });                   
        }
    );
    console.log(result[0].id); //Undefined     
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an async issue. `db.transaction` takes a callback which executes after the sqlite transaction finishes. Your `console.log()` statement shown at the end of your method is actually happening before `result` has been populated.

EDIT ADDITION:

```
functions getPersons() {
  returnSQLArray('SELECT * FROM PERSONS', processPersonsResponse); 
}

function returnSQLArray(str, callback) {
  ...
  tx.executeSql(str, [], function(tx, rs) { callback(result); });
}

function processPersonsResponse(response) {
  //do work with response
}
```

Comment: I was worried that it was the case. Is there anyway to solve this? I've seen some solutions, where people have used the setTimeout method to avoid the async issue. Is there a better way?

Comment: is there a reason why you can't just do all the work required inside the callback?

Comment: I have to use the results array in the function where I call it. Example: Inside a function called getPersons i want to call returnSQLArray('SELECT * FROM PERSONS') and then use the array inside the function afterwards.
I wouldn't be able to return it from my callback function, right?

Comment: @user1698462 - see my edit above for one way to do what you are suggesting. Please mark my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is it possible to return the array from processPersonsResponse to my initial function getPersons?

Comment: @user1698462 - no because you run into the same problem, anything in `getPersons` after the `returnSQLArray` call will actually happen before the person response is processed.