# javascript - OOP - executeSql return the result into a var , it shows undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, oop, callback

I'm trying to use Phonegap function executeSql to fetch a SQL Query with a select statement , i'm just want to return a query results from my OOP function
i read this question 
[Return executeSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360055/return-executesql-function)
but i can't undrestand it well so i can't apply it on my code

```
function Invoice() {
    this.read = function(){
        var stmnt = "SELECT * FROM invoices ORDER BY ID DESC";
    function callback(callback_fun){        
        var myrows = [];
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql(stmnt, [], function(tx,result){
                for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    myrows.push(row);
                }
                //console.log(myrows);
                callback_fun(myrows);
            }, function(tx,error){
                alert('Error: '+error.message);
                return;
         });
     });
    }
    callback(function(newResult){
        return  newResult;
     });
   };
};
var newInvoice = new Invoice();
var myResult = newInvoice.read();
alert(myResult);
```

Comment: see my update. just added some jsbin examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your *callback()* plus *callback_fun()* as an return value like this:

```
function Invoice() {
     this.read = function(){
         var stmnt = "SELECT * FROM invoices ORDER BY ID DESC";
         function callback(callback_fun){        
            var myrows = [];
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql(stmnt, [], function(tx,result){
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                        var row = result.rows.item(i);
                        myrows.push(row);
                    }
                    //console.log(myrows);
                    return callback_fun(myrows); // <<----- RETURN
                }, function(tx,error){
                    alert('Error: '+error.message);
                    return;
             });
         });
     }
     return callback(function(newResult){ // <<<<<<<<----------- RETURN
        return  newResult;
     });
   };
};
```

What Javascript Callstack looks like:

1. you are calling *Invoice.read()*, but read-Function has no return keyword so it doesn't return anything, what leads to *undefined*
2. You are calling your callback function. Which also returns nothing.

**EDIT2:**
Oh ok you are invoking another function db.transaction which currently returns the value to your callback function. So you could probably do that:

```
function callback(callback_fun){        
    var myrows = [];
    return db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(stmnt, [], function(tx,result){
            for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                var row = result.rows.item(i);
                myrows.push(row);
            }
            //console.log(myrows);
            return callback_fun(myrows); // <<----- RETURN
        }, function(tx,error){
            alert('Error: '+error.message);
            return;
        });
     });
 }
```

**EDIT:**
This is your code. Oh Well a little bit simplified: [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/dicecegugo/edit?html,js,output)
This is my code. [JSBIN-Working Example](https://jsbin.com/fetaziyugu/edit?html,js,output)
You need to press **Run with JS** in the right corner.

Comment: it's also still return undefined

Comment: When i try 
`return callback(function(newResult){
            alert(newResult); // Shows a great working message 
            return  newResult;
        });`
it's appear an alert contains the objects :/ 
alert() is working but return is not !!!

Comment: you set both return keywords!? you are returning your method call `callback(function(){...});` and this is returning something too?